# android : dialogue while exiting application

Tags: android, dialog

i want to exit my application when no network
Before exiting i want to show a message to user
Which dialogue can be used for this.

i tried to DISPLAY ALERT DIALOGUE  from OnDestroy()

But its giving window leak exception

The network error is detected in asynctask where i call finish, so i dont see any other place to add dialogue.

So my question is which dialogue to add and where to add.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    showExitDialogue();
    Log.i("StartUpActivity", "OnDestroy");
    if (asyncTaskForSync != null && !asyncTaskForSync.isCancelled())
        asyncTaskForSync.cancel(true);
    if (mydb != null)
        mydb.close();
    if (Utils.imageLoader != null)
        Utils.imageLoader.stopThread();

}
private static void showExitDialogue() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Utils.getStartActivityinstance());
    alert.setMessage("No internet connection");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Exit",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {
                    return;
                }
            });     
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check network error  in asynctask,then the dialog should put at  the onPostExecute(Void v)

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I had to change the logic also a bit to call finish of main activity from the postExecute function private static void showExitDialogue() {
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    Utils.getStartActivityinstance());
  alert.setMessage("No internet connection");
  alert.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    Utils.getStartActivityinstance().finish();
   }
  });
  alert.show();
 }